# Set Session variable inside php controller

Tags: session

I'm from custom php world but It looks like I can't just set a session variable in plain php.
I'm playing around

```
use craft\web\Session;
...
$session = new Session();
$session->open();
$session->set("a", 'b');
```

or other choice, Craft::$app->getSession()->set("a", "b");

But i don't see it working, I don't see my storage session added in any way.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Yii2 components behave a bit like singletons, you shouldn't create new ones manually. Instead, accessing them over the `Craft::$app` property is preferred, as you indicated. This should work:

```php
$session = Craft::$app->getSession();
$session->set("a", "b");
```

How are you checking if the session value got set? It's likely you're just looking in the wrong place, the default session component is file-based now if I recall correctly. You can check if a session variable exists and/or what value it holds like this:

```php
Craft::dd($session->has('a'));
Craft::dd($session->get('a'));
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed ! 
Thank you very much, it works !